# Trouble with Javascript object properties - Eloquent Javascript example

Tags: javascript, object, properties, expression

```
var thing = {"gabba gabba": "hey", "5": 10};
show(thing["5"]);
thing["5"] = 20;
show(thing[2 + 3]); // = 20
show(thing[2]); // = undefined
show(thing[3]); // = undefined
```

I do not understand why show(thing[2+3]) = 20 and the other two below it return undefined. What do the 2 and 3 refer to? Could someone help me out with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `thing[2]` means to find a property on the object named `thing` with the name `"2"`.  Since property names are strings, the number `2` is automatically converted to the string `"2"`.  Since that object has no such property, the result is `undefined`.

The expression `thing[2+3]` means to first evaluate `2+3` which is `5`.  Then `5` is converted from a number to a string `"5"`, and then find the property on `thing` with that name.  Thus the result is `20`.

Comment: Thanks dsh, you answered it perfectly. I'd upvote but I don't have the reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why show(thing[2+3]) = 20 and the other two below it return undefined.

`thing[2+3]` evaluates to `thing[5]` (`==20`), but properties with the names "2" or "3" don't exist on your object - and therefore yield `undefined` when being accessed.

> What does the 2 and 3 refer to?

They're plain number literals.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that thig is not an Array, it is an Object (key : value pairs).
If you like to get "hey" youd need to do:

```
show(thing["gabba gabba"]); // = "hey"
```

And because there is an entry with key "5", 2 + 5 works:

```
show(thing["5"]);   // = 10
show(thing[2 + 3]); // = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the 5th term of *"thing"* the value of 20

```
thing["5"] = 20;
```

Javascript is clever enough to understand that when you type

```
thing[2 + 3]
```

What you really want is

```
thing[5]
```

What you're not doing is

```
thing[3] + thing [2]
```

However, *thing[2]* and *thing[3]* have no value, hence, they return as undefined. You'd need to give them a value, like you did before when you gave *thing[5]* a value of 20.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way JavaScript Objects work. You can consider them as a kind of HashMap with keys and values.

In your example you've got a HasMap object called `thing` which has only 2 pair of key-values. `"gabba gabba"` is the key for the first one with `hey` as its value, the second pair has `"5"` as its key and `10` is the value. To make it more comprehensible we have a function called `Object.key()` in JavaScript which gives you the collection of keys you have in your object:

```
Object.keys(thing);
```

which its result is:

```
["5", "gabba gabba"]
```

as you see there is no `2` or `3` in the keys, so if you want them to be there you should add a pair with these keys and your desired values:

```
thing[2] = "whatever";
thing[3] = "whatever";
```

then the key collection would be:

```
["5", "gabba gabba", "2", "3"]
```